# extension points for classpath

Tags: java

I want to create an extension point in Eclipse, where someone can define a `classpath`. I want the extension point to have two fields, one for the Id and one for the pathname. But after that what I have to do?

Do I have to use this "Classpath Container Initializers"? I am confused could you please give me some advise?

Comment: Have a look in Java7 nio2 package